use expect command to configure zyxel accesspoint
I can configure my Accesspoint via console and now I want to do this bulk via expect command. It does not work and i suspcect that the problem is that expect does not like : in variables.
This is my script. I expect expect to send $macadress to the console of my accesspoint. But it stays empty. While debugging sometimes I saw the first two chars of my macadress being shown. Does expect not work with variables containing colons? However, i tried escaping colones which also did not work.
A possible usage might be
expect block-mac.expect aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff accpoint-01

#!/usr/bin/expect

# Usage block-mac.expect <mac-adress> <hostname-accesspoint>

set macadress [lindex $argv 0];
set accesspoint [lindex $argv 1];

puts $accesspoint
puts $macadress

spawn ssh admin@$accesspoint.mydomain.com

expect "*assword:" { send „super_secure\r“}
expect "Router" { send "enable\r"}
expect "Router#" { send "configure terminal\r"}
expect "Router(config)" { send "wlan-macfilter-profile mac-filter\r"}
expect "Router(config-wlan-macfilter mac-filter)#" { send "filter-action deny\r"}
expect "Router(config-wlan-macfilter mac-filter)#" { send "$macadress\r" }


I found the solution. I added 'sleep 1' between the commands. expect seems to send commands faster than my accesspoint can operate

Adding 'sleep 1' did the trick. It was not a fault of 'expect'-command but my accesspoint was too slow.
